# iTunes track notifications for Mountain Lion

Tags: itunes, terminal, dock, macos

In OS X Lion there was the preference (via a Terminal command) to enable iTunes track notifications that were displayed as a popup in the dock.

So far it seems as though Mountain Lion does not allow this, I was wondering if anyone knew whether the command had changed or if this is just not possible in OS X 10.8.

The Terminal command I had been using in Lion was:

`defaults write com.apple.dock itunes-notifications -bool TRUE; killall Dock`

Answer (score 3):

As best as I've been able to tell, this feature has been removed.

There are two alternatives to the Lion-provided notification mechanism that provide a few more features and customizability.

If you have Growl installed, you can use [GrowlTunes](http://growl.info/extras.php#GrowlTunes) to provide Growl notifications on track and playback changes.

The official [Last.fm Scrobbler](http://www.last.fm/download) app provides notifications via Growl as well, the bonus being that it's worth using if you also scrobble your playback history to Last.fm. If you don't you probably want to stick with GrowlTunes.

[Growl](http://growl.info/) is a generic notification system with a large amount of customizability, like the ability to customize the alert style. Growl has existed for OS X for as long as I can remember, years and years pre-dating even Tiger, iOS, and the Notification Center as well.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned on [Mac OSX Hints](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20120827235540457) today: [iTunification](http://onible.com/blog/2012/08/13/itunification-itunes-integration-with-notification-center-in-os-x-mountain-lion/) will display all played titles in Notification Center (source code included).

> When you play songs in iTunes or Spotify, this application gets the track name, artist, and album name of that song and shows it in Mountain Lion’s new Notification Center or Growl. This is your choice.

Answer (score 0):

As seen here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4173481?start=0&tstart=0, you can use NowPlaying, which gives a notification on iTunes track change.

NowPlaying download: http://www.mediafire.com/?93f8id99zi6s4r9

Answer (score -2):

This is not the exact fix you are looking for, but is a close alternative.
http://hyperdock.bahoom.com/
"HyperDock adds long awaited features to your Dock: Select individual application windows just by moving the mouse on a dock item, use mouse clicks to quickly open new windows and many more"

Comment: It doesn't even seem like a close alternative. The OP asked about some kind of notification when iTunes switches to the next track.