# iTunes - what playing now notifications

Tags: itunes, mac, macos, music, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iTunes track notifications for Mountain Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56093/itunes-track-notifications-for-mountain-lion)

I want to turn on iTunes notifications on Mountain Lion?
Anybody knows how I can do this?
Growl dosn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

### Enable iTunes track notifications in the Dock

In the terminal type

```
defaults write com.apple.dock itunes-notifications -bool true
```

Reference (with a lot of other great terminal commands):: [nerdlogger.com](http://nerdlogger.com/2012/07/30/get-control-of-mountain-lion-with-a-huge-list-of-command-line-tweaks/)

Comment: You are welcome. But are you sure that it actually works? There are some reports that it doesn't work in ML any more.

Comment: I dont think it does, or is it iTunes 10.7?